# Can a .mobi file be used with Xcode to make an app for the App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

My son and his friends wrote a 65,000-word interactive adventure book/game this summer and have saved the project as a .mobi file. I know they can sell their creation at Amazon with a simple conversion to a prc or ePub file, but they would like to go through the process of submitting their creation to the App Store.

I'm willing to help them pay their fees and get what equipment they need but after a day of research, it seems they'll have to build the project from scratch as .mobi isn't really a format that lends well to making an app. Can their .mobi file be imported into Xcode or is the .mobi useless to this process?

Thank you all for your time and expertise.

Jennifer

Comment: Is the document not available in any other source format? What was the original document created in, before it was made into a .mobi?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid converting a .mobi file to iOS App isn't as straight forward as you think. If you can submit the file to Amazon, you can as well make it available to users of iPad through Amazon's official Kindle App.